# Is there a way to easily propose tag deletion except by making a meta post?

Tags: support, editing

[This post](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/181303/maintaining-a-public-handbook-collaborative-editing-online-viewing-plus-good) had the tag [t](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/t) on it - I have edited the post and deleted the tag. But once created, the tag continues to exist. From the looks of it, this tag was created by mistake and should thus be deleted. Yet, on the tag site, there is no possibility of flagging a delete-worthy tag (or I did not see it.)
Is there an easier way to bring such a tag to attention of users of sufficient reputation than to make a post here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank you for removing the tag!

There is a daily script that automatically removes the unused tags, so no need to take any further action.

Comment: perfect, thank you for that info.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to look at the "New" tags every day. Often enough there is a tag there with a single question but no tag wiki. Sometimes I'll leave it (and think about appropriate wiki). Sometimes I'll edit the question and supply other tags instead, deleting that one.

I left [persistent-identifiers](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/persistent-identifiers) and [reprint](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reprint) as they seem to me to be useful, though the latter still has no wiki.

Not every keyword in a post should be a tag (IMO).